# Why is my object not find other Gameobject name?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to destroy my object when it will enter in OnTriggerEnter method.
I am using something similar this code

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider C)
    {

        if(C.name == "GameObject Name")
        {

            Destroy(gameObject);
            Time.timeScale=0;
        }
    }
```

my object enter into OntriggerEnter event but it can't find  `C.name == "GameObject Name"`  .

Sorry friends, now one problem is occured..actually my object is not detect collider gameobject.I mean my object is not enter in trigger event. .now What can I do?

Comment: just to let you know that if it is a instantiated prefab, there will be a "(clone)" at the back of the GameObject name.

Comment: @KennethLJJ, I know that but I am not using  instantiated prefab.     [kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html).

Comment: so what's the actual problem? is `OnTriggerEnter` called or not?

Comment: @Kajal if you want to detect a collision then make sure both objects have Collider component on them and the one with the script actually has a script attached to it and then you can reference it like `c.gameObject.Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use Tag option on the object. Right corner of the Unity choose Tag 'Player' From Inspector and apply this code[C#].

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision){
       if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
          Destroy(Object_name_to_destroy);
          Time.timeScale=0;
          }
     }
```

Comment: Can u elaborate your problem. Which object you have to delete. Entering to Collider object or other. Set Tag to which object is entering to colleder.

Comment: Sorry @Rasa Mohamed, now one problem is occured..actually my object   is not detect collider gameobject.I mean my object is not enter in trigger event. .now what can i do?  [kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: Ensure your Collider IsTrigger option is checked and add script to the collider to which object you applied

Comment: I do those things..but still its not working.many times I destroyed object using OnTriggerEnter method..but I don't Know why its not working today. [kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: use Destroy(Gameobject.Find("Your_Object_Name"));

Answer (score 0):

You want the name of the GameObject belonging to the Collider, so use `C.gameObject.name`.

Comment: I used this code but it is not working [kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is super late but for someone facing this issue in future...try checking for blank spaces after your game object name i.e "example_name " is different from "example_name"